# cannot call php script from $.post()

Tags: php, jquery

I need to call php script from html - say index.html in localhost. I am trying $.post() of jquery, which fails and I cannot debug the problem. Any help from any body?

As a demo, say I want to call info.php, i.e.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and I try to call info.php by the following code

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
alert('Submitting data');
$.post('./info.php');
});
```

I get the alert from the above function, but the rest remains silent.

info.php and index.html both reside in the root directory of localhost.

Comment: And what do you expect? What should happen?

Comment: It's the expected behaviour, you made a succesful request with nothing that gets returned.

Comment: Actually, I need to send data from two input fields, without form. So with $.post(), I want to run a php script which will connect to mysql and insert the values of the two input fields of the html file, into a table.Since I cannot find out whether the jquery is at all callinf the php script, I can make no further progress

Answer (score 0):

You use the post function alright, but you don't apply any callback to perform actions when post completed. Try the success callback function :

```
$.post('./info.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // do whatever you want here
} );
```

see the doc :

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

You also should consider use the ajax function of jquery. You can parameter the request type handle success, error, complete etc..

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling `.post()` does not do anything in the browser. If you want something to happen then you have to tell the browser to do whatever you want it to do.

For example, you can output the returned data to the Javascript console:

```
$.post('./info.php').done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

To see the console output hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. Go to the "Console" tab.

Comment: Actually, I need to send data from two input fields, without form. So with $.post(), I want to run a php script which will connect to mysql and insert the values of the two input fields of the html file, into a table.

Comment: Since I cannot find out whether the jquery is at all callinf the php script, I can make no further progress

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to load the response in the current page (index.html) you can use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method for that:

Let's say that in the page `index.html` you have the following `div`:

```
<div id="phpinfo"></div>
```

Then the following code should load response from `info.php` into the `div`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#phpinfo').load('info.php');
});
```

Now, to load the response using [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method you would have to use the following:

```
$(function() {
    $.post('info.php', function( data ) {
        $('#phpinfo').html( data );
    });
});
```